# How to protect a web server from massive XSS Scanners?

Tags: web, server

My web server got a hundred odd tries of accesses from Acunetix scanner within 1 minute!

How can I avoid these attacks, seeing that I have many different end users accessing the website per minute?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways you can tackle this:

- Setup tools such as [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to automatically block IPs for users scanning your website.
- Automatically block any requests using custom headers. In this case, see your web server's access log and see whether or not it is sending any custom headers similar to:

> Acunetix-Product: WVS/X (Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner - NORMAL)
>
> Acunetix-Scanning-agreement: Third Party Scanning PROHIBITED
>
> Acunetix-User-agreement: http://www.acunetix.com/wvs/disc.htm

You can then block such patterns possibly using web server rules or a WAF (Web Application Firewall).